# SQL Server Reporting Services Service Application Encryption Error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, reporting-services, sql, service-application

I'm trying to create a new SQL Server Reporting Services Service Application, I go in and set all my settings and the application creates just fine. But when I click on the service application i created and click "System Settings" I got this error:

The report server cannot decrypt the symmetric key that is used to access sensitive or encrypted data in a report server database. You must either restore a backup key or delete all encrypted content. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportServerDisabledException: The report server cannot decrypt the symmetric key that is used to access sensitive or encrypted data in a report server database. You must either restore a backup key or delete all encrypted content. ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Requested registry access is not allowed.

Whats funny is that on my SQL server I totally deleted the Reporting database from SQL manager, and then used "Reporting Services Configuration Manager to create a new database with a different name and I'm still getting this error. Has anyone else ever come across this? I'm stuck and confused as to why it is doing this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using Reporting Services Configuration Manager with SSRS 2012 or higher when in SharePoint integrated mode. That is why you're seeing this error. Delete your existing SSRS Service Application and databases, then create a new SSRS Service Application with new databases.

Comment: The only thing i have that is 2012 is SQL manager. My SharePoint Enterprise is actually 2010, sorry I should of pointed that out. So I create the service application first THEN the database? I've been creating the database first then the service application, does that matter?

Comment: When you create the Service Application, it will create the database as well. You can name the database, or leave the database name as the default. You should not use any tools outside of SharePoint to create or manage SSRS databases when in SharePoint integrated mode.

Comment: I just tried it but when i try to go to system settings after i created it using SharePoint only, i still have the same error as above. Is this because there is another report database still somewhere?

Comment: SSRS has 3 databases, they should all start with the same name (e.g. ReportingServices, ReportingServices_Temp, ReportingServices_Alerting).

Comment: Correct. All were removed and when I created a totally new service it created new databases, but i still got the same error, so not sure why it's happening.

Comment: So i found out that native mode and SharePoint were both installed. I uninstalled reporting services, for native mode AND SharePoint and rebooted the server. After it came back up, I reinstalled the Reporting Services - SharePoint. In central admin i saw the service running, and then proceeded to installed the service application, everything installed fine, but i still get the above original error, any other ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: Trevor, I found another link of yours (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c683975b-7f8b-477c-bc43-1016c290adfa/report-service-integration-sql-2012-and-sharepoint-2013-error-report-server-wmi-provider-error?forum=sharepointgeneral) and tried to follow those instructions whats weird is that once i removed the reporting services from my SharePoint site under the services the sql service was still installed and running?

Comment: Sorry i know I keep adding comments.. just trying to provide as much info as possible for help...
So after i created the sql service app, i created a new doc lib turn on management and then add my reporting options. when i try to add a new data connection i get this: "An unexpected error occurred while connecting to the report server. Verify that the Reporting Services Service Application mapped to this web application is available OR the report server is available and configured for SharePoint Integrated mode." the app service is mapped to my web app and all services are running. I'm stumped.

Comment: Might be difficult to work on this based on the information provided. Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219068(v=sql.110).aspx which walks you through the installation of SSRS on SharePoint.

Comment: I Install Reporting Services Report Server in SharePoint mode on my SPE server not my SQL server correct?

Comment: Must be installed on a SharePoint server that is a member of the farm.

Comment: Thanks for all your help btw Trevor. I removed all the roles and rebooted, i noticed it actually removed SQL Server 2012 (64Bit) from my programs list, so now I'm following the above guide and its currently installing, everything matches so far.. so I'm crossing my fingers for when it finishes. Maybe i had some corrupt files, I'm not really sure will let you know once install is completed.

Comment: So after the install completed, I went in checked to see if the SQL service was running, and it was (in SharePoint) I then created a brand new SQL Service Application. I went to my SharePoint site and created a new doc lib to test it by trying to add a new data connection type and i get this error: "An unexpected error occurred while connecting to the report server. Verify that the Reporting Services Service Application mapped to this web application is available OR the report server is available and configured for SharePoint Integrated mode. "  and the app service is mapped to my site... :(